# Issue with drawing - squares not displaying properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

Ok so: my code for Main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyFrame();
        
    }

}
```

my 'Drawing' code:

```
     import java.awt.AWTException;
     import java.awt.BasicStroke;
     import java.awt.Color;
     import java.awt.Font;
     import java.awt.Graphics;
     import java.awt.Graphics2D;
     import java.awt.MouseInfo;
    // import java.awt.PointerInfo;
     import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
     import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
     import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
     import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

     import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;
     import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
     import javax.swing.JButton;
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;





     public class MyFrame extends JPanel{
         
        public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            public JPanel myCanvas = new JPanel();
        public  JButton play = new JButton();
        
        MyFrame(){
            
        frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setTitle("Drawing game test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
            frame.setCursor(1);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3, false);

            Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD,25);
            
            myCanvas.setBounds(150,150,300,300);
            myCanvas.setVisible(false);
            myCanvas.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            frame.add(myCanvas);

            play.setFont(font);
            play.setBounds(150,195,200,50);
            play.setText("'Play'");
            play.setFocusable(false);
            play.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            play.setBorder(border);
            play.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(play);
            play.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        play.setVisible(false);
                            paintComponent(getGraphics());      
                }
                            
                

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
            });
            
            
     }

        
        


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            
            System.out.println("I display this if I work");
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2D = (Graphics2D) myCanvas.getGraphics();
            super.paintComponent(g2D);
        g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5f));

        g2D.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    
            }

     }
```

Essentialy all it does is make a visible jframe, and when you clicl a button it paints on a jpanel.
Im not getting any errors, though the square looks weird, like a square passed through it.
This hasnt happened before, and Im weirded out as to what couldve happened to the square.

When I call my paintComponent manually and removing the button temporarily there isnt an issue, but when the button is there it interferes with the drawing process?

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout 2) Don't use getGraphics() to do custom painting. 3) Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a complete working example. The tutorial will show you how to structure your code properly.

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).